# Apply filter to an entity within an object using JSONPath

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "value": {
    "activate": false
  }
}
```

I want the JSONPath value to returned as true, but on applying the filter as below:

```
$.value.?(@.activate==false)
```

I get an invalid result.

Is there anything wrong with the JSONPath?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're expecting to be returned?  JSON Path is a query language, so you should expect to get a subset of the values contained within the original document. The path you're using is invalid, but to help properly, I need to know what you want to do.

Comment: @gregsdennis Thank you for your response. I am trying to evaluate the condition $.value.?(@.activate==false) and have it returned as true. Is there a way to go about that?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for filter queries needs brackets.

```
$.value[?(@.activate==false)]
```